# How to find first result from Mongo within Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The following works for finding an array of results.

```
    collection.find({name:query}).toArray(function (err,result) {
        if(err)
            sendError(db,err,request,response);
        else
            displayResults(db,result,request,response);
    });
```

However, I want to simply find the first result.

Comment: use `findOne` instead of `find`?

Comment: If I just plug that in it throws an error about the toArray operation, any tip on how to fix that?

Comment: Look at the [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html) or the output itself. It doesn't return an array, just a single object. It means you don't need `toArray`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [findOne()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#findOne):

```
collection.findOne({name:query}, function (err,result) {
    if(err)
        sendError(db,err,request,response);
    else
        displayResults(db,result,request,response);
});
```

Or take the first element of the array you get:

```
collection.find({name:query}).toArray(function (err,result) {
    if(err)
        sendError(db,err,request,response);
    else
        displayResults(db,result[0],request,response);
});
```

Keep in mind that `findOne()` returns an object with just one result (if any), not an array. In both cases checking the result could be a good idea.